# android:name value in androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, cordova

Although my app name is showing correctly on emulators and real devices, in androidmanifest.xml it currently reads `android:name="HelloCordova"`

```
<activity 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="HelloCordova" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

Should I change the HelloCordova to what my app name is or is it ok to leave as-is? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

`android:label` and `android:name` are completely different.

- `android:label` is the name that will show up on emulators and real devices as you've observed.
- `android:name` is "An optional name of a class implementing the overall 
  android.app.Application for this package. [string]".  This attribute is used when you have a custom class that extends `Application` that you want to use.  This attribute should be a class prepended by its package.  You can just use one period to use the application's package.

Example:

`android:name="com.myapp.CustomApplication"` or `android:name=".CustomApplication"`.

Comment: Where did you get the quote for android:name? I was subclassing Application and wanted to read more about it, to see if I need to include it in the Manifest.

Comment: @3366784 you can read more about it here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#nm

Answer (score 4):

`HelloCordova` here is the name of a class extending `Activity` in (your) code.

What you see on `ActionBar` or elsewhere is `android:label="@string/app_name"`, which is (most probably) defined in `res/string.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

The `android:label` will help you change your application name.
If you want to use `android:name`, the class must be extends class `Application`.